# Can I use NavigationView with SherlockFragmentActivity?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

I'm looking to use the `NavigationView`, part of the Android design support library, instead of a `ListView`.

I use `SherlockFragmentActivity` part of the **ABS** *framework*, my question is how can I use `NavigationView` with ABS (without usnig Appcompact) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) requires AppCompat as per the [release blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html):

> Note that as the Design library depends on the Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries

As it uses AppCompat for consistent theming across all API levels.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AppCompatDelegate to enable AppCompat in your SherlockFragmentActivity. An official example of that is: https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java